# get the post_date of ID

Tags: get-posts

How can I get the post date of ID?

this is my code

```
$id = "13"; //wp_posts ID
get_post_date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $id) //is there something like this in wordpress?
```

I dont like to create a custom query if possible.

Comment: try get_the_time("Y-m-d H:i:s", $id); insted of get_post_date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $id);

Answer (score 2):

You may please use `<?php $pfx_date = get_the_date( $format, $post_id ); ?>` to get the date